# Is "Value" actually the default property of the Range object?

Tags: vba

Before I begin I want to say that I realize you should never depend on default properties and I won't, but this is curious.  I've always read that `value` is the default property for the `Range` Object, hence why this works:

```
Range("A1") = 2
```

However, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) page claims that `item` is the default property of `Range`.

Additionally, this sub I made would suggest that `cells` is the default property instead:

```
Sub defaultprop()

Dim c As Variant


For Each c In Range("A1:A2")

    Debug.Print c.value

Next c

For Each c In Range("A1:A2").value

    Debug.Print c

Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: I think that it is too strong to say that one "should never depend on default properties". If I want to reference Sheet2 I see no reason to write `Sheets.Item(2)` rather than `Sheets(2)`.

Comment: @JohnColeman I believe the OP's general message was about default properties that don't have parameters. The ones that do are perfectly fine and where shipped to .NET to live long and well.

Answer (score 9):

The default member of the `Range` class is called `_Default` and is hidden. When you enable the "Show Hidden Members" feature in the Object Browser you can see it:

[image: VBA Object Browser]

<strike>It has the exact same signature as the `.Item` property, so one of them is arguably an alias for the other.</strike><sup>(*)</sup>

In any case, `Range` also implements the collection interface. As such, it can be used in a `For Each` loop — and when you do that, the loop will call `.Item` with each iteration and assign the current item to the loop variable.

When used outside an enumeration, for example with `Debug.Print`, then `.Value` will be used, but I can't really explain why. Maybe someone else can come up with a hint.<sup>(*)</sup>

---

<sup>(*)</sup> As @GSerg [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996772/#comment53824568_32997154) in the comments, `_Default()` and `_Item()` are not exactly equal.

Comment: Do you mean the `item` property instead of the `item` method?  If I try to explicitly use the `item` property I get an `Argument not Optional` message since it requires at least one argument

Comment: Actually the distinction between *property* and *method* is blurrier than one might think. A *property* consists of two functions, a getter and a setter. Getting a property value means calling the property's getter function. Especially in this case, where the getter can handle two argumens: `.Item(row, col)`. If it was called `.GetItem(row, col)`, everyone would say that's a *method*, even if all that had changed was the name. So, yes, technically `.Item()` is a *property* of the `Range` class, but it's more a concept and less of a substantial difference.

Comment: The `_Default`'s signature is not exact same signature as the `.Item` property - the first parameter is optional in `_Default` and required in `Item`. The only explanation that I can come up with from the COM point of view is that `_Default` is the only true default property, and it calls either `Item` or `Value` depending on whether or not a parameter was supplied. Note that if a parameter was supplied, `_Default` will not call `Value`, even though `Value` accepts a parameter too.

Comment: @GSerg Now that you say it, it makes absolute sense. I have overlooked the difference in the signatures. That's the explanation. That I can't say `RangeObject(1)` in VBA has to do with the fact that `_Default` is marked as hidden?

Comment: @Tomalak it's [not that hidden](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SV1tr.png) ;) and no, that's not because you can't say `Range(1)`. You can't say `Range(1)` because you're calling the `Application.Range` method which is not happy with this parameter. This is different to declaring a `Range` variable, where you certainly can say `r(1)` to return the first cell.

Comment: I tried with `ActiveSheet.UsedRange(1)` and that doesn't work either. But where's the difference?

Comment: This has to do something with late binding (weird things may happen with late binding and default properties, there was a link somewhere but I can't find it). If you declare a `Worksheet` variable, then `w.UsedRange(1)` works fine.

Comment: Which might actually be seen as a compiler bug to tell you the truth; VB should be able to resolve this at runtime no problem. What happens is that it tries to pass the `1` parameter to the `UsedRange` property *itself*, as opposed to the default property of the object returned by `UsedRange`. You can work around this by using the function-style syntax: `MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange()(1)`, even though `UsedRange` is not a function.

Comment: Well, technically it "is" a function. VB interprets the parameter as an argument for the getter, just as with `.Item(1)`. The ambiguity arieses when thr getter accepts arguments and the returned object's default member does the same. IMHO, properties are nothing but syntactic sugar for reducing the funtion count on an object, collapsing getters and setters into one.

Comment: @GSerg What's really strange is that `TypeName(sheet1.Cells.[_Default](1,2))` returns `Range`.

Comment: @ThunderFrame Why is that strange? With two parameters, `_Default` apparently [calls `Item`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996772/is-value-actually-the-default-property-of-the-range-object/32997154?noredirect=1#comment53824568_32997154) which returns a range.

Comment: @GSerg Well, it seems you *can* call the implicit default member all the way through the returned Ranges: `sht.Cells(1, 2)(1, 1)(1, 1)(1, 1)(1, 1)(1, 1)` and yet you can't explicitly use `[_Default]` beyond the first call, like this: `sht.Cells.[_Default](1,2).[_Default](1,1) 'Runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method`. See the RD [issue](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3153)

Comment: @GSerg I think this [article by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/08/30/vbscript-default-property-semantics/) is the article you couldn't find. It also links to further information in another blog [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/05/04/simplescript-part-seven-binder-skeleton/)

Comment: @ThunderFrame I don't remember seeing that; great reading though. I was thinking about a question here about weird things which I couldn't find.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it appears that Value is default property of Range.

I put a very large number in cell A1.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "Range default = " & Range("A1") & vbCrLf _
        & "Range Text = " & Range("A1").Text & vbCrLf _
        & "Range Value = " & Range("A1").Value & vbCrLf _
        & "Range Value2 = " & Range("A1").Value2
End Sub

Results in 

Range default = 3.24643541346456E+28
Range Text = 3.25E+28
Range Value = 3.24643541346456E+28
Range Value2 = 3.24643541346456E+28
```

Notice that Range("A1")'s result is identical to Range("A1").Value and Range("A1").Value2

Comment: It's also idential to `Range("A1").Cells(1).Value` and `Range("A1").Cells.Item(1).Value`...

Comment: When the `Range` instance is used outside of a `For Each` loop I'd say that's correct.