# Range() vs Cells() vs Range.Cells()

Tags: vba, excel

I know that the `Range()` and `Cells()` properties are equivalent methods of accessing cells on a worksheet. However, when is it wise to use `Range.Cells()` in this combination?

I came across an example where they used `Range("A1").Resize(2,3).cells.value`.
Would this be equivalent to `Range("A1").Resize(2,3).value`?

If not, what is the advantage of the former?

Comment: Range.Resize is for altering the height and width of the row and column, so all of your examples using resize(2,3).value return errors. So, I guess they are equivalent in the sense that they don't work. :-)  ... Whether you use just `range` or `cells` or any of the other methods of referencing cells depends mostly on the size of the range and what you are trying to do, whether you will be looping though cells or acting on all at once, etc. If you can post an example of what you are trying to do, I can probably give you some case-specific help.

Comment: @SeanW333 that's wrong. `resize(2,3).value` will not return an error. It will just return a valid array of values of that range.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I get an "Invalid use of property error" when I run either `Range("A1").Resize(2,3).value` or `Range("A1").Resize(2,3).cells.value`. So, at least on my system, it would seem I'm not wrong.

Comment: @SeanW333 Well, `Dim c:  c = Range("A1").Resize(2, 3).Cells.Value` should return an array in `c`. Also see my answer below. This definitely works when used correctly.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I tested using exactly what the op posted, since there was no additional context provided, and both lines caused errors. I'm glad you came along and were able to correctly guess what they wanted to do.

Comment: @SeanW333 well more to the point your issue was that "Range.Resize is for altering the height and width of the row and column" is wrong. Range.Resize changes the shape of the range.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically, `Range` and `Range.Cells` are not equivalent. There is a small but important difference.

However **in your particular case**, where you

1. Construct the range with `Range("something")`, and
2. Are only interested in the `.Value` of that range,

**it makes no difference at all**.

---

There is a handy clause in VB, `For Each`, that enumerates all elements in a collection. In the Excel object model, there are convenient properties such as `Columns`, `Rows`, or `Cells`, that return collections of respective cell spans: a collection of columns, a collection of rows, or a collection of cells.

From how the language flows, you would naturally expect that `For Each c In SomeRange.Columns` would enumerate columns, one at a time, and that `For Each r In SomeRange.Rows` would enumerate rows, one at a time. And indeed they do just that.
But you can notice that the `Columns` property returns a `Range`, and the `Rows` property also returns a `Range`. Yet, the former `Range` would tell the `For Each` that it's a "collection of columns", and the latter `Range` would introduce itself as a "collection of rows".

This works because [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450309/11683) there is a hidden flag inside each instance of the `Range` class, that decides how this instance of `Range` will behave inside a `For Each`.

Querying `Cells` off a `Range` makes sure that you get an instance of `Range` that has the `For Each` enumeration mode set to "cells". If you are not going to `For Each` the range to begin with, that difference makes no difference to you.

And even if you did care about the `For Each` mode, in your particular case `Range("A1").Resize(2,3)` and `Range("A1").Resize(2,3).Cells` are the same too, because by default the `Range` is constructed with enumeration mode of "cells", and `Resize` does not change the enumeration mode of the range it resizes.

---

So the only case that I can think of where querying `Cells` from an already existing `Range` would make a difference, is when you have a function that accepts a `Range` as a parameter, you don't know how that `Range` was constructed, you want to enumerate individual cells in that range, and you want to be sure that it's cells `For Each` is going to enumerate, not rows or columns:

```
function DoSomething(byval r as range)
  dim c as range

  'for each c in r ' Wrong - we don't know what we are going to enumerate

  for each c in r.cells ' Make sure we enumerate cells and not rows or columns (or cells sometimes)
    ...
  next
end function
```

Answer (score 6):

Both

```
Dim b As Variant
b = Range("A1").Resize(2, 3).Cells.Value
```

and

```
Dim c As Variant
c = Range("A1").Resize(2, 3).Value
```

will return the same array of values. So they are equivalent. No advantage which one you use (one is shorter).

[image]

---

But you can use

```
Range("A1").Resize(2, 3).Cells(1, 2).Value
```

to get a specific cell out of that range. So this is the most likely where you need the `.Cells` on `.Range`.
Note that the row/column numbers in `Cells(1, 2)` are relative to the range not the absolute numbers of the worksheet.

So the differences are:

```
Range("A1:A2")              'range can return multiple cells …
Range("A1")                 '… or one cell.
Cells(1, 2)                 'cells can return one cell or …
Cells                       '… all cells of the sheet

Range("A1:A2").Cells        'returns all cells of that range and therefore is the same as …
Range("A1:A2")              '… which also returns all cells of that range.

Range("C5:C10").Cells(2, 1) 'returns the second row cell of that range which is C6, but …
Cells(2, 1)                 'returns the second row cell of the sheet which is A2
```