# Difference between ways of referencing value of a cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a range variable in VBA consisting of a consecutive block of horizontal cells, say,

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("A1:H1")
```

I want to reference the value in the 3rd position in this range to use it in a calculation (I do not need to change the value in this cell). I've found at least 8 different ways to do this:

```
myRange(1,3)
myRange(3)
myRange(1,3).Value
myRange(3).Value
myRange.Cells(1,3)
myRange.Cells(3)
myRange.Cells(1,3).Value
myRange.Cells(3).Value
```

Is there any difference between what these different methods are doing? Which one(s) are preferable and why? I'm particularly confused by what happens when I do `myRange.Cells` - it seems like that would just return `myRange`. It's also not entirely clear to me what type of object is returned by `myRange(1,3)` (or `myRange(3)`, etc.).

Comment: `what happens when I do myRange.Cells`  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097214/11683

Comment: @GSerg Thank you, so I understand the ```.Cells``` is not necessary for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using these expressions in a non-reference context ([without `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683)), there is [implicit `.Value`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683) at the end of each one that does not have it explicitly. This leaves us with:

```vb
myRange(1,3).Value
myRange(3).Value

myRange.Cells(1,3).Value
myRange.Cells(3).Value
```

Now, these are in fact different.

- `myRange(1,3)` queries *`Range` that is at RowIndex 1, ColumnIndex 3* of `myRange`.

  If `myRange` happens to have [enumeration mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097214/11683) of "cells", the expression will return the cell at those coordinates, but if `myRange` is enumerated as "rows" or "columns", you will have an exception:

  ```vb
  Dim r As Range

  Set r = Me.Range("A1:H1")
  Debug.Print r(1, 3).Address  ' $C$1

  Set r = Me.Range("A1:H1").Columns
  Debug.Print r(1, 3).Address  ' Run-time error 1004
  ```
- `myRange(3)` queries *`Range` that is the third item* of `myRange`.

  What *item* means is, again, determined by the [enumeration mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097214/11683) of `myRange`.  For "cells", it will return the third cell, counting left to right and then top to bottom. For "rows" or "columns", it will return the entire third row or column:

  ```vb
  Dim r As Range

  Set r = Me.Range("A1:H10").Columns
  Debug.Print r(3).Address  ' $C$1:$C$10

  Set r = Me.Range("A1:H10").Rows
  Debug.Print r(3).Address  ' $A$3:$H$3

  Set r = Me.Range("A1:H10")
  Debug.Print r(3).Address  ' $C$1
  ```

  In case the mode is "rows" or "columns", and provided that `myRange` contains multiple of the counterpart dimension ("columns" or "rows"), the `.Value` will return a 2D array. Attempting to use it in a scalar context will raise a type mismatch exception.
- The versions with `.Cells` remove the uncertainty described above and let you operate on the version of `myRange` that is enumerated as "cells". You are now guaranteed to have those of the above outcomes that correspond to the "cells" enumeration mode.

In conclusion, when working with ranges of unknown origin, the safest thing to do when you want *the third cell of the first row* is `myRange.Cells(1,3).Value`. It also happens to express the intent in the clearest way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough and clear answer!