# How can I see the NewEnum method that for each calls?

Tags: vba

In the microsoft docs for 'collection', it says that

> Collections must implement a method called NewEnum that accepts no
> arguments, returns an appropriate IUnknown object, and has its
> VB_UserMemId attribute set to -4.

If I look at 'Collection' in the excel VBA object browser, I can only see Add, Count, Item and Remove.

How do I see that Collection has a NewEnum method? Where do I see documentation for its NewEnum method? Is there any way to see the source code?

Many thanks!

Comment: Right click - Show hidden members.

Comment: Ah great - thank you! Is there any way to see the actual implementation in the Collection class? I'm also trying to understand the Range class, and I can't see anything in the docs that says what to expect Range _NewEnum to return. It seems to be returning Range Objects, but I can't see that written anywhere.

Comment: Browsing source code for `_NewEnum` is no more possible that browsing source code for `Count` or `Item`. There isn't source code. It has been compiled. The `Range`'s enumerator however [is interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097214/11683).

Comment: Ah thank you! That's very interesting.. Your answer in that other link is very useful - thank you!

Comment: The `_NewEnum` allows you to use it in a `For Each` loop. That is its purpose. In Basic the standard array, which in BASIC is not an object, also emulates the `_NewEnum` as if it was a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are Standard Objects defined in the COM Automation standard. This was written at the same time as VBA and for VBA. A programmer has to implement the collection.

A collection is created by a program according to some rules. *There is no source code as it a standard that programmers must follow to create a collection*. It purpose is to enable the `For - Each` construct.

VBA has an implementation of a generic collection for programmers to quickly use but advise not to use it in code that other code calls. You are supposed wrap VBA's generic collection in a class. You can stick anything in VBA's generic collection and you write a class to restrict what can be added.

When you get a collection from Excel Excel works out what to give you by what object you asked for in your `For Each` loop. EG `Rows` inherit from `range` so you treat it as a `range` object as it has same properties and methods. Under COM rules it could have more methods but not fewer than the `range` object. If you ask a rows object, via IUnknown:QueryInterface, are you a range it will answer yes.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-ienumvariant

> **Collection Object Properties**
>
> A collection provides a set of objects over which iteration can be
> performed. All collection objects must provide the following
> properties:
>
> **Property name Return type Description**
>
> ```
> Count  VT_I4 Returns the number of items in the collection; read only. Required. 
>
> _NewEnum  VT_DISPATCH A special property that returns an enumerator object that 
> implements IEnumVARIANT. Required.
> ```
>
> **IEnumVARIANT Interface**
>
> The IEnumVARIANT interface provides a method for enumerating a
> collection of variants, including heterogeneous collections of objects
> and intrinsic types. Callers of this interface do not need to know the
> specific type (or types) of the elements in the collection.
>
> Implemented by Used by Header file name
>
> Applications that expose collections of objects Applications that
> access collections of objects Oleauto.h (32-bit systems)
>
> Dispatch.h (16-bit systems)
>
> The following is the definition that results from expanding the
> parameterized type IEnumVARIANT:
>
> ```
> interface IEnumVARIANT : IUnknown { 
>    virtual HRESULT Next(unsigned long celt, 
>                VARIANT FAR* rgvar, 
>                unsigned long FAR* pceltFetched) = 0;
>    virtual HRESULT Skip(unsigned long celt) = 0;
>    virtual HRESULT Reset() = 0;
>    virtual HRESULT Clone(IEnumVARIANT FAR* FAR* ppenum) = 0;
>    };
> ```
>
> To see how to implement a collection of objects using IEnumVARIANT,
> refer to the file Enumvar.cpp in the Lines sample code.
>
> **IEnumVARIANT Methods Description**
>
> ```
> Clone Creates a copy of the current state of enumeration. 
> Next Gets the next items in the enumeration sequence 
> Reset Resets the enumeration sequence to the beginning. 
> Skip Attempts to skip over the next celt elements in the enumeration sequence.
> ```