# Why does For Each over Range.Columns(1) not iterate over cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I can iterate over a range of cells to operate on each cell individually, if the range is specified by address:

```
Dim cell as Range
For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
  debug.print cell.Address
Next cell
```

Produces the expected output:

```
$A$1
$A$2
... etc
```

But when I specify a column from the `Columns` collection of a range, iteration only runs once with the whole column:

```
For Each cell In UsedRange.Columns(1)
    Debug.Print cell.Address
Next cell
```

Produces just one output, with the whole column:

```
$A$1:$A$20
```

Is `UsedRange.Columns(1)` not a `Range` object? If not, what is it??

I've read [this discussion of Rows/Columns as ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448228/2071807) and [this on Range vs Range.Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097214/2071807) but I still can work out how to iterate over each cell in `UsedRange.Columns(1)`.

Comment: `For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns(1)` loops the entire column for me, so I guess it's the fault of how UsedRange works. Which I'd have to research more tbh.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Iterating over `ActiveSheet.Columns(1)` has exactly the same problem as I'm describing. You get one iteration, with address "$A:$A", not many iterations one for each cell in the column. So it's nothing to do with `UsedRange`.

Comment: That's odd, I used that, with `cell.Value = 1` in the loop, and it filled the entire column with 1's. But when trying `UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells` I only get `A1`

Comment: _Is UsedRange.Columns(1) not a Range object? If not, what is it??_ - it is a Range object, but a special one. `For Each` iterates all elements of collection. If you check `Count` property for _normal_ `$A$1:$A$20` - it is 20, but if you create same `Range` using Columns(i), the `Count` is 1. I don't know any other property to distinguish normal and row/column ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because a `Column` is a distinct Object itself.  If you loop over columns, you loop one column at a time.  To loop over the **cells** in a column:

```
Dim cell as Range
For Each cell In UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
  debug.print cell.Address
Next cell
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but notice that I'm not iterating over `Columns`, I'm iterating over `Columns(1)`. This still takes a bit of further explaining I'd say. It has to do with the fact that `Columns(1)` doesn't do quite what I think it's doing.

Comment: @LondonRob  Actually you **ARE** iterating over columns, but the iteration is over only ONE column ! ..........................this is quite confusing................I asked the same question myself several years ago.........................