# using predefined names in VBA

Tags: vba

The code is really simple and I'm just trying to copy values in from_range and paste them in to_range. But it's just not working out...

```
Sub test14()
    Range("to_range") = Range("from_range")
End Sub
```

Before,

[image: Before]

After, not sure why everything in to_range is gone

[image: After]

Desired, just want to overwrite to_range with from_range

[image: Desired]

Could someone explain what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: `Range("to_range").Value = Range("from_range").Value`, but I wonder why that does not happen automatically, because it should. Specifically it's the absence of `.Value` after `Range("from_range")`; `Range("to_range")` may or may not have `.Value`, that does not change the outcome.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or it just empties the `to_range`? Verify the named ranges, are they the same size?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The OP is showing what happens: it clears out the `to_range` (I've reproduced that).

Comment: @GSerg fair enough, though "it's not working" isn't the most descriptive, esp. when images don't render.

Comment: What are `Range("from_range").Address` and `Range("to_range").Address` values?

Comment: It's extra weird because explicitly calling the default property (`Range("to_range").value = Range("from_range").[_Default]`) does the right thing, but implicitly it does not. I wonder if [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32996772/11683) has something to do with it.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you! Adding .value worked. I'm still curious as to why the code does what it does, I will read into the discussion you shared.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm not getting any error. The code just empties the to_range, at least that's what it appears to be. The colored ranges in the pictures are to_range and from_range. Sorry I just thought posting images are the most efficient way to describe it. You can try this code with any named ranges with the same dimensions.

Comment: Morale of the story: write code that *says what it does*, and *does what it says* - i.e. avoid implicit default member calls, invoke `.Value` explicitly.

Comment: Oddly enough `Range("to")=[{1,2,3,4}]` works just fine.  It must have something to do with how Excel handles ranges which are objects and not variables - they have to be `SET` after all.  Strange how using properties fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the question coping the range and pasting special like explained above:

```
Sub test14()
    Range("from_range").Copy
    Range("to_range").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I hope it helps you!

Regards,
Pedro Azzam.

Comment: With this code, you can paste only values from a range to other, so all the formated cells keep like before. If you want to paste formats as well, just change "PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" for "Paste". 

Regards, 
Pedro Azzam.

Answer (score 2):

also you can do this job with Select:

```
Range("from_range").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("to_range").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```