# Conversion from type Range to Double is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to transfer some data from excel to an array in VB so that it can be used later on in my code.  I have imported the office interop and defined what excel woorkbook to open and the correct sheet to activate. However once I rune through the loop I get the error "System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'Double' is not valid.'"

Is anyone familiar with this and point me in the right drection over what the error is?

```
    Dim OSpointsX(8) As Double
    Dim OSpointsY(8) As Double

    Dim MyExcel As New Excel.Application
    MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("...\Dims Update sheet 3D.xlsx")

    'extract
    MyExcel.Sheets("Sheet2").activate()

    For i = 0 To 8
        OSpointsX(i) = MyExcel.Cells(i + 3, 1)
        OSpointsY(i) = MyExcel.Cells(i + 3, 2)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, default properties have to have parameters. `Value`, being a parameterless [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683) of `Range`, does not qualify like it did in VBA.

Specify `Value` explicitly:

```
OSpointsX(i) = MyExcel.Cells(i + 3, 1).Value
OSpointsY(i) = MyExcel.Cells(i + 3, 2).Value
```

Comment: Looking through all of the complex problems and trying commands such as CType was tearing my hair out..... Who know it was so simple....

Comment: A two items for your consideration. 1) [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Value) is not parameterless.  2)The default property on `Range` is the property `_Default([rowIndex],[colIndex])` (hidden in VBA, use show hidden properties in the Object Explorer). To use it in VB.Net to return the value, omit the index properties.  i.e. `MyExcel.Cells(i + 3, 1)()`.  If you supply the indices in VB.Net, it will return a `Range` object`.  Please note that I do not advocate using the default property.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yes, [you are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32997154/11683). I might have oversimplified it.