# Worksheet.Columns property asks me for a RowIndex?

Tags: excel, vba

If I write this in the VBA editor:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Columns(
```

*IntelliSense* shows me a seemingly unrelated tooltip:

> _Default(**[RowIndex]**, [ColumnIndex])

The `Worksheet.Columns` property only accepts the index (column) number as far as I can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns).

So why am I asked for a `RowIndex`? Why does it refers to `_Default` (and what is it)?

Comment: See the screenshot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32997154/9245853). `Columns` returns a `Range`, and `_Default` is the default member. Hopefully someone like Mathieu Guindon can provide a more thorough answer. His article [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/) about default members is a good read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Worksheet.Columns property only accepts the index (column) number as far as I can see in the documentation.

Nowhere in the documentation does it say the `Columns` property takes a parameter, and indeed, it would be wrong to mention that, because it doesn't have any:

[image: Worksheet.Columns definition in Object Browser]

Like `Worksheet.Rows`, `Worksheet.Columns` yields a `Range` object. So when you "parameterize" it, what's really happening is this:

```
Set foo = ws.Columns.[_Default](value)
```

Any argument you provide, get interpreted as arguments to an implicit default member call against the `Range` object that was *returned* by the call to `Columns`.

You may have read somewhere that the default member of a `Range` is its `Value` - and that is not true. The default member of a `Range` is a hidden property named `[_Default]` (square brackets are required in VBA if you want to invoke it explicitly, because no legal VBA identifier can begin with an underscore), that takes two optional parameters:

[image: Range._Default hidden property in Object Browser]

When you read ("get") this default property without providing any arguments, this default property *does* get you the `Range.Value` (i.e. a single `Variant` value for a single cell, or a 2D `Variant` array for multiple cells). When you assign to this default property, you *are* assigning the `Range.Value`.

But when any arguments are provided when reading ("get") this default property, what you get is a call to the very standard `Range.Item` indexer property:

[image: Range.Item definition in the object browser]

So what `Columns` does, is simply take your input range, and yield a `Range` object laid out in such a way that it can be accessed using a `RowIndex` argument - we can prove this using named arguments, which show that this code is illegal:

```
?Sheet1.Range("A1:C1").Columns.Item(ColumnIndex:=2).Address
>> "wrong number of arguments"
```

As is this equivalent code:

```
?Sheet1.Range("A1:C1").Columns(ColumnIndex:=2).Address
>> "error 1004"
```

Note that the `_Default` property yields a `Variant`, so the above `.Address` member call can only be resolved at run-time (and you don't get any intellisense for it, and the compiler will not flinch at any typo, even with `Option Explicit` specified - you *will* get error 438 at run-time though).

Best stick to safe early-bound land, and pull the returned object reference into a local variable:

```
Dim foo As Range
Set foo = ws.Columns(1)

Debug.Print foo.Address '<~ early-bound w/intellisense & compile-time validation
```

---

TL;DR: You're being prompted for a `RowIndex` argument because you *are* making a call (albeit an *implicit* one) to a hidden `_Default` property that accepts a `RowIndex` argument.

Comment: Great answer - this is why I deferred to you in my original comment. Great read and thorough. Thanks for taking the time to lay it out.

Comment: Wow, thanks Mathieu for this lesson and sorry for my delayed reading and approval!